# Is it possible to adjust position of an inserted image with openxlsx?

Tags: r, excel, openxlsx

I've created an excel template for reporting. In the excel file, there will be some images. I'm able to insert the images by using openxlsx package.

```
test.fpath <-'Templates/CB.xlsx'
wb <- openxlsx::loadWorkbook(test.fpath)
insertImage(wb, sheet = 1, file = "tm_player_image.png",startRow = 8,  startCol = 3, width = 1.1, height = 1.73, units = "in")
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "createWorkbookExample.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

openxlsx package allows you to set specific value for starting row and column. When I run the script, excel file is saved like the following image.

First position of the image:
[image: First position of the image]

However, I don't want the image start row = 8 and col = 3. I should able to drag the image where ever I want and define top-left position values. Is there any way to achieve this?

Adjusted position of the image
[image: Adjusted position of the image]

I need to define position of the image like this.

- Left (Sol): 13,64''
- Top (Üst): 0,74''

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but there is no function to do this and AFAIK Excel positions are always relative to the screen and OS one is using. Therefore you have to use a bit try and error to get the correct positions.

Have a look at `wb$drawings[[1]][[1]]`. The content is an XML string. You are looking for the `xdr:from` part (as seen below). You have to adjust `xdr:colOff` and `xdr:rowOff` like in the example below. I had to insert a fairly high value to see any impact.

```
<xdr:from xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing">\n
<xdr:col xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing">2</xdr:col>\n
<xdr:colOff xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing">50000</xdr:colOff>\n
<xdr:row xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing">4</xdr:row>\n
<xdr:rowOff xmlns:xdr="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/spreadsheetDrawing">40000</xdr:rowOff>\n
</xdr:from>
```